# Trying to get property of non-object in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

error code in view line 16

```
<tr>
                <td width="30%">ID</td>
                <td><?php echo $siswa->id;?></td> //line 16
            </tr>
```

controller code

```
function view($id=1){
            //set common propesties

            $data['title'] = 'siswa Details';
            $data['link_back']= anchor('siswa/index/','Lihat daftar siswas', array('class'=>'back'));

            //get siswa details
            $data['siswa'] ='';
            $data['siswa'] = $this->siswa_model->get_by_id($id)->row();

            //load view
            $this->load->view('siswaView',$data);

        }
```

i am confused because i has been initialized $data['siswa'] ='' ; in controller but still error in view line 16. can you help me solve this error?

Comment: This error occurs when you are trying to treat an array like an object. Use `print_r()` to see what is the outcome of your `$data['siswa']`.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you don't have any object on `$data['siswa']` so in view calling `$siswa->id` will show you the error because your model `get_by_id($id)->row()` gives empty result fix there or check in view

```
if (is_object($siswa)) {
        echo $siswa->id;
    }
```

or

```
if (isset($siswa->id)) {
        echo $siswa->id;
    }
```

[**is_object**](https://www.php.net/is_object)